# NiFi NiPyApi gives me errors

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I managed to get at Kerberos ticket and perform some task with canvas object, but I still face some issues. 
I have wrapped the code into a class and have those 2 functions

The first function `getBulletinBoard` retrieves all messages in the bulletin board  from NiFi in it works fine:

```
def getBulletinBoard(self):
    canvas_id = canvas.get_bulletin_board()
    return canvas_id
```

The second function Stop Processor should stop a processor doesn't work, I have hardcorded my processor id into this for test reason and tried various thing to make it work.

```
def stopProcessor(self):
    try:
        canvas.schedule_processor('d73136a7-6b8d-1914-a511-3c5acb2b5515',scheduled=False)
    except nifi.rest.ApiException as e:
        print(e.body)
        return None
```

The output for `StopProcessor` function is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Temp\nifi-rest\test1.py", line 176, in <module>
n.stopProcessor()
File "c:\Temp\nifi-rest\test1.py", line 162, in stopProcessor
canvas.schedule_processor('d73136a7-6b8d-1914-a511-  3c5acb2b5515',scheduled=False)
File "C:\python3.6_32\lib\site-packages\nipyapi\canvas.py", line 528, in  schedule_processor
assert isinstance(processor, nipyapi.nifi.ProcessorEntity)
```

AssertionError

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: Can I please check, do you have any Process Groups on your canvas?

Comment: @Chaffelson i have many process-groups on my canvas. It is a kerberos secured nifi installation. I can do operations on my processors with the nifi API and curl

Comment: I'm just testing this on my side.
The error in your code in your latest edit is that schedule_processor expects to be passed a nifi.ProcessorEntity object, and you are giving it a UUID for a processor. Please try nipyapi.canvas.get_processor('d73136a7-6b8d-1914-a511-3c5acb2b5515', 'id')

Comment: Thank you very much it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an Answer so the question can be closed:

The error in your code in your latest edit is that schedule_processor expects to be passed a nifi.ProcessorEntity object, and you are giving it a UUID string from the processor.

Please try getting the Processor object using a call like:
`nipyapi.canvas.get_processor('d73136a7-6b8d-1914-a511-3c5acb2b5515', 'id')`

In future, you can use the 'help' command on any call to see what parameters it is expecting, and the same information is available in http://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/